# How to complete the IF statement with a formula in Xcode?

Tags: xcode8

I am very new to Xcode and Swift. I have been trying to complete the if statement with a formula below. I noticed that I cannot copy and paste the Swift if statement into Xcode 8 directly.

It shows a yellow triangle: result of operator '-' is unused.

Please help to complete the code so that the answer will be shown in the 'answer' label. Thank you.

### *More information:

### This is a simple app I am building. The user will enter 2 numbers (k1 and k2) and click the button (b1) to generate an answer ('answer' label).

### The button (b1) will convert the texts (k1 and k2) to integers (p1 and p2) respectively. Then it will decide: if p1 is greater than p2 (say 5 is greater than 2), it will execute p1 - p2 and show the answer (3) in the 'answer' label. Else, it will execute p2 - p1.*

```
@IBOutlet var k1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var k2: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var answer: UILabel!

@IBAction func b1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let p1: Int? = Int(k1.text!)
    let p2: Int? = Int(k2.text!)

    if p1! > p2! {
    p1! - p2!     //shows yellow triangle: result of operator '-' is unused.
        }

    else{
    p2! - p1!    //shows yellow triangle: result of operator '-' is unused.
    }
}

//to show the result of p1 - p2 or p2 - p1 in 'answer'.
```

}

Comment: Give more information.

Comment: You have used `Int(k1.text!)` to parse text to produce an integer, so you understand the need to convert/parse a value in one type to produce a value in another type. After parsing your strings to produce integers you do some calculation to produce the answer you require as an integer. So your final hurdle is to convert your integer to a text representation you can use on your label. This is the same kind of operation you started with - conversion - which you've shown you know how to do. If you've tried this and failed edit your question to show this, if you haven't tried then do so!

Comment: But it shows a yellow triangle: result of operator '-' is unused. So I cannot proceed.